# xcode Search Locations on MapKit

Tags: iphone, xcode, search, dictionary

I want to search places like google map in my app with using MKMapView. I searched and find that i should use webview with integrating google map api. However, i don't want that. Is there any service that i can send place name as input and it returns appropriate results with locations,names,address etc. When i look for google map service, i think it is not free  , thus i can not use it.

For example:

I send  boston university as input
it will return
Boston University
lat:xxxxx
lng:xxxxx
Address:xxxxxx

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `BSForwardGeocoder` it makes the process incredibly easy.

https://github.com/bjornsallarp/BSForwardGeocoder

Comment: Thanks for response, actually, this is what i'm looking for but i want to ask; is it free to use this in my own app ? Because i don't want any legal issue after i use it on my own app.

Comment: From the link: "The source is unlicensed and 100% free for you to use with whatever you want."